# Validating numericality of postgres integer field in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

my postgres database table was setup with

```
t.integer :time_employed
```

I had validations like so

```
validates :time_employed, numericality: true, allow_blank: true
```

and I also tried

```
validates_numericality_of :time_employed, allow_blank: true
```

But neither of them gave me the result I was looking for. I did some testing in the console and it seemed that the field was always being set to `0` or `nil`. If I input a string it was being set to `0`.

I changed the database field to

```
t.string :time_employed
```

and now everything works like it should. It's not a huge problem, but I was hoping to keep the data correctly described by the schema.

I don't know much about databases yet, so this threw me for a loop. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

EDIT:

The problem was that it would allow blank entries, but it wouldn't throw an error if I input non numeric values. Anything would be validated as good, just not saved to the DB. After changing to `t.string` and no changes to the validations, it worked fine.

I also tried `allow_nil: true` but it had the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
validates_numericality_of :time_employed, allow_blank: true
```

by

```
validates_numericality_of :time_employed, allow_nil: true
```

**allow_blank** is not present in [api docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_numericality_of) this may be one of the reason.

Comment: The question was edited. I tried `allow_nil` also but it had the same outcome. The weird thing was, with `t.integer` it wouldn't error with non numeric values. After I changed to `t.string` and no change to the model, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

because your `time_employed` column is type-casted before validation.

```
validates_numericality_of :time_employed_before_type_cast, allow_blank: true
```

should work.